# App doesn't run it crashed directly after I started it

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have a problem, this is my code:

```
DataTable DT1 = new DataTable();

public static DataTable DATASETRETURN(string queryString)
{
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();

    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter
            {
                SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, CLSERVICES.CON)
            };
    adapter.Fill(DS, "TABLE");

    return DS.Tables["TABLE"];
}

private void FE_C_HISTORIQUE_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    E_HISTORIQUE_LV_HISTORIQUE_04.Items.Clear();
    string req = "select H.NHistorique, P.Intitulle, H.QuantiteVendu, P.PrixVente,"+
                 "(P.PrixVente * H.QuantiteVendu) as PQ, H.TypeAction, H.DateAction " +
                 "from HISTORIQUE as H, PRODUIT as P" +
                 "where (P.NProduit = H.NProduit)"+
                 "order by H.NHistorique desc";
    DT1 = DATASETRETURN(req);

    for (int i = 0; i < DT1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        ListViewItem LV = new ListViewItem(DT2.Rows[i][0].ToString());
        LV.SubItems.Add(DT1.Rows[i][1].ToString());
        LV.SubItems.Add(DT1.Rows[i][2].ToString());
        LV.SubItems.Add(DT1.Rows[i][3].ToString());
        LV.SubItems.Add(DT1.Rows[i][4].ToString());
        LV.SubItems.Add(DT1.Rows[i][5].ToString());
        LV.SubItems.Add(DT1.Rows[i][6].ToString());

        E_HISTORIQUE_LV_HISTORIQUE_04.Items.Add(LV);
    }
}
```

After I run the app, I get an error in method `DATASETRETURN` oin the line

```
adapter.Fill(DS, "TABLE");
```

The error is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   "\"P\" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90."

Is there is any solution?

Comment: You're missing spaces at the ends of some of your sql strings.  Example, "...PRODUIT as Pwhere(P.NProduit...".

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `DT1 = DATASETRETURN` in your debugger and look at what `req` contains.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Thanks @Gaber-be for giving me the source of probleme.

Comment: thank you @dourHighArch i will try it next time :)

Comment: @marc_s why it s a bad habit , what's the avantages that make  join best than a code like i write it , i don't say that i right the code or the requet in the best way i still beginner but just i want to know ;) :)

Comment: Did you **read** the blog post I linked to?? It explains in great detail why it's preferred to use **explicit ANSI/ISO JOINs** instead of comma-separated lists of tables ....

Comment: oh sorry i ll read it now i didn't see it until now , but i ll read it now :) :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem caused by the missing spaces between "P_where" and between "H.NProduit)_order"

when specifying multiline queries I prefer:

```
string req = @"
  select H.NHistorique,P.Intitulle,H.QuantiteVendu,P.PrixVente,
   (P.PrixVente*H.QuantiteVendu)as PQ,H.TypeAction,H.DateAction
  from HISTORIQUE as H, PRODUIT as P
  where(P.NProduit = H.NProduit)
  order by H.NHistorique  desc
";
```

this way you decrease the chance of missing new lines in your queries.

Comment: ok thanks for now i know the solution of a new problem thanks a lot.